# WWW sub-folder not executing?

Tags: apache2

I have installed ubuntu server on my system, after  installation, I also installed lamp server.

However, the problem is : i created a empty folder in var/www, the folder directory is var/www/mobile. I visited the URL localhost/mobile and it was working but the folder was empty. Then I added an HTML file in the mobile directory - var/www/index.html. I used vi var/www/index.html to create the file.

After adding the index.html in var/www . I visited again localhost/mobile but now the computer is treating the directory as a downlodable file. Each time I visit the URL the web-browser is asking me to save the directory. I tried on the iPod and this massage came out " cannot download the file".

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen on all browsers? You could have a problem with the default MIME type. Let's learn what the browser sees. Install Firefox Web browser, and then the Firefox extension, [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/). Now, what MIME type or Content-Type was sent to the browser? You will see many headers, but the important one now is **Content-Type**. For XHTML you might see these among others...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 25 Dec 2011 19:48:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Content-Length: 750
Content-Style-Type: text/css
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml
```

Now look at your Apache config files, specifically the AddHandler and AddType directives. The default type is text/html. What is your Apache using?